# How to get subprocess stdout while running git command?

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I have a program written in python and used git command in it..
For some reason I don't want to use git-python or others instead of subprocess.
But I'm currently stuck in getting `git clone` output.

I've tried some code snippet. Some works fine with commands like `ping 8.8.8.8`, but not the `git clone`.

for example

using thread

```
def log_worker(stdout):
    while True:
        last = non_block_read(stdout).strip() 
        if last != "":
            print(last)


def non_block_read(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.read()
    except:
        return ''

def test():
    mysql_process = subprocess.Popen(
        "ping google.com",
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    thread = Thread(target=log_worker, args=[mysql_process.stdout])
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    mysql_process.wait()
    thread.join(timeout=1)

test()
```

or

```
newlines = ['\n', '\r\n', '\r']
def unbuffered(proc, stream='stdout'):
    stream = getattr(proc, stream)
    with contextlib.closing(stream):
        while True:
            print('tt')
            out = []
            last = stream.read(1)
            # Don't loop forever
            if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                break
            print('last', last)
            while last not in newlines:
                print("loop")
                # Don't loop forever
                if last == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                    break
                out.append(last)
                last = stream.read(1)
            out = ''.join(out)
            yield out

def example():
    cmd = ['ls', '-l', '/']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        # Make all end-of-lines '\n'
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell = True
    )
    for line in unbuffered(proc):
        print('new line')
        print line

example()
```

and most common one

```
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
    sys.stdout.write('{:.2f}  {}\n'.format(
        time.time() - start,
        line.rstrip()
    ))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

all of them works fine with `ping google.com`, but not `git clone`.
Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE1:
In face, I'm just want to get the finished percent of `git clone`. Log or any log files are not needed.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` (especially since you're using an argument list rather than a shell command line)?

Comment: wouldn't subprocess.check_output be a whole lot easier?

Comment: Also, in what word is the last version "most common"? When have you ever needed log-style timestamping but not wanted to use the `logging` module?

Comment: related: [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279)

Comment: look at [`pty.spawn()` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25968448/4279)

Comment: @AndrewC if you tried, you will find it returns `returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: @abarnert because I'm just want to know the progress of `clone` :P

Comment: @RobinZhang: Which one of my questions is that an answer to? Using `shell=True` doesn't have any effect on getting the progress. Adding your own fake version of `logging`-style output doesn't either.

Comment: That might be a windows problem, subprocess.check_output works fine calling clone on linux.

Comment: @AndrewC: When I do it on both Fedora 19 Linux and OS X 10.10 beta, I get no stdout ever, and no stderr except on error. Of course that "works", and it's exactly what's documented, but if the OP wants the progress output that gets generated on a TTY, it's not doing what he wants.

Comment: @RobinZhang: If it's returning non-zero exit status 1, that means your clone failed. That's a whole separate problem that you also have to fix (although arguably capturing the stderr, as you're trying to, might help in that case…)

Answer (score 5):

When not writing to a terminal, `git clone` doesn't have any output to either stdout or stderr, except on error.

When writing to a terminal, of course, it has lots of output—but that output is progress bars that are continually overwritten. Usually, you don't want that—it's going to be a big mess of control characters and repeated lines.

But if you *do* want it, there are two options.

---

First, you can use a PTY (Pseudo-TTY). You can create a PTY with [`os.openpty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.openpty), then hand the PTY off explicitly to the child process. Or you can use [`os.forkpty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.forkpty), which handles forking and automatically hooking up the PTY so all you have to do is call one of the [`os.exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-management) functions. Or you can use the [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html#module-pty) module. (It's not entirely clear which is more portable; `openpty` and `forkpty` claim that `pty` is more portable, and conceptually it's designed that way… but it's also only really tested on Linux.)

Note that `git` wants the PTY as its stderr, not its stdout.

---

Alternatively, most `git` commands have a `--progress` flag that causes them to write progress to stderr even if it's not a terminal. At least as of the version documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), this includes `clone`, but of course you should check the `man` for your local version. So, that *may* be all you need. (Also see the `--verbose` flag.)

However, this may not be as nice. For me, when I provide a PTY with no attached termcaps, I get each line followed by a `\r` without `\n` to overwrite it; when I use the `--progress` option, `git` detects the termcaps of whatever terminal my script happens to be running it, which means I end up getting ANSI color codes as well as `\r`s.

---

Of course either way I'm getting hundreds of useless lines that I have no interest in, but I assume that's what you wanted? (Or maybe you want to use `universal_newlines='\r'` to translate the `'\r'` to `'\n'`? That's slightly cheating, because this is self-overwriting Unix terminal output, and you're pretending it's classic-Mac output… but it works.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I assume that the PTY solution would be painful on over-cross platform? My program must runs on Windows 7 and MacOS.

Comment: @RobinZhang: On Windows there's no way to use a PTY. (Windows does have a similar concept, but Python doesn't try to wrap the two concepts up in a single API.) So I suppose `--progress` is the only option. But first: does the problem actually happen on Windows in the first place? Many command-line apps don't do the `isatty` check at all on Windows, which means you can just use a PTY on Unix and do nothing special on Windows…

Comment: Thanks ! `--progress` is what I wanted !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I also wanted real-time progress because the `git clone` was taking a long time (like 5 minutes), since it was a large git repo.  And I wanted to provide real-time feedback to the user.

Here is a Python 3.7 working example:

```
# This will print stdout/stderr as it comes in
def run_shell_command_with_realtime_output(shell_command_string, working_dir='.'):
    # print the command to be executed, just for fun
    print("run_shell_command >", shell_command_string)

    # run it, this will NOT block
    sub_process = subprocess.Popen(shell_command_string,
                                   shell=True,
                                   cwd=working_dir, universal_newlines=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    # print the stdout/stderr as it comes in
    while True:
        # The readline() will block until...
        # it reads and returns a string that ends in a '\n',
        # or until the process has ended which will result in '' string
        output = sub_process.stdout.readline()
        if output:
            print(output.strip())
        elif sub_process.poll() is not None:
            break

    # get the return code
    return_code = sub_process.wait()

    # Was there an error?
    if return_code != 0:
        print("FYI, the subprocess had an error, you might want to do something special...")

    # return the sub_process, in case the caller wants to check exit/return codes
    return sub_process
```

It turns out `git clone` does not seem to write to stdout/stderr like we normally are used to.  Instead it uses a pager, which is how it updates the same line, like when it is cloning, and the % is incrementing on the same line.

So you need to call it like this.

```
# prepare to clone the git repo
git_clone_url_with_credentials = "https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/myreponame.git"
git_clone_with_progress_cmd = "git --no-pager clone --progress {}".format(git_clone_url_with_credentials)
helpers_misc.run_shell_command_with_progress(git_clone_with_progress_cmd)
```

And that should do it...