# Python - execute a bash command, print and save the output in the same time

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

From Python, I want to execute a bash command (maybe with subprocess.Popen()) and I want to print the output and also to save the output in a variable or in a file, at the same time.
This command returns a lot of text and it takes some hours to run.

If I redirect the output to a file, can I immediately print every new line which appears in this file?

Comment: See the `tee` command.

Comment: related: [How do I push a subprocess.call() output to terminal and file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25963074/4279)

Comment: related: [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279)

Comment: related: [Python subprocess get children's output to file and terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984428/4279)

Comment: related: [Subprocess.Popen: cloning stdout and stderr both to terminal and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17190221/4279)

Comment: @isedev: `tee` might not help: 1. the child process may change what it prints if it detects that the output is a pipe (`| tee`) 2. the output may be not immediate due to block buffering 3. the child process may print to terminal directly (outside of stdout/stderr). 4. You may want to save stdout/stderr separately. See the references above that show how to resolve these issues

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this all in Python, without the `tee` command, you can.  Basically you need to set `stdout=PIPE` (see the subprocess docs), then use `select()` on it, to be notified whenever there is a chunk of data to read.  When there is data available, read it and write it to a file and print it at the same time.  A solution to a similar problem which you can adapt for this purpose is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272262/4323