# how to write to the terminal without writing to process.stdout or process.stderr?

Tags: node.js, tty

I would like to log things to the terminal without writing them to `process.stdout` or `process.stderr` so that piping the process doesn't end up being polluted by those logs.

That's very much the equivalent of `echo "hello" > /dev/tty` in bash (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405200/write-to-terminal-after-redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-without-using-stderr)), but I can't find how to directly access `/dev/tty` from node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open it as a file and write to it :)

```
var fs  = require('fs');
var tty = fs.createWriteStream('/dev/tty');

console.log('hello');
tty.write('foo\n');
tty.write('bar\n');
```

Comment: Can this be used for windows as well, or is there a windows-equivalent of this?

Comment: @Automatico I have no idea, but should be easy to test :D If it doesn't work, perhaps `fs.createWriteStream('CON')` does (but I don't use Windows so can't test).

Answer (score 0):

so I found a way, but that could be considered cheating ;)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
process.stdout.write('writing to stdout')
exec("echo 'writing to the terminal without writing to stdout' > /dev/tty")
```